# I am getting token error which is not matching with session in the request

Tags: jmeter

I am getting below error in jmeter performance testing
ERROR:
The token in the request does not match the one in the session!
Scenarios:

1. user logs into the appln
2. click on the modify user from the menu
3. search for the user
4. select the user
5. adding roles to the user
   6.click submit
   7.click on return to search button.
   8.click on logout.

I am getting the csrf token in the post method and i captured the csrf token in 2 samples before in the GET method.I added regular expression in GET method and i used that regular expression variable in the Post method token.

Please let me know how to fix the token error.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to provide a comprehensive response without seeing network dump of requests from the real browser and from JMeter, most probably you need to extract the CSRF token from **every** response, not "2 samples before", try moving your Regular Expression Extractor to the same level as HTTP Request samplers  - this way it will be applied to all of them and will extract the "fresh" CSRF token from each response. See [JMeter Scoping Rules - The Ultimate Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-scoping-rules-the-ultimate-guide) article for more information

As per [Cross-Site Request Forgery Prevention Cheat Sheet](https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet.html)

- > The site then requires that every transaction request include this pseudorandom value as a hidden form value (or other request parameter/header)`
- > The following guidance will demonstrate how to create overrides in JavaScript libraries to have CSRF tokens included automatically with every AJAX request for the state changing methods mentioned above.
- > CSRF tokens should be generated on the server-side. They can be generated once per user session **or for each request**.